# I want to access inner array data from array object of data in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
myData = [{
    "Total_Demand": "800",
    "weekly": [
      {
        "CycleTime": .65,
        "Demand": 650,
      },
      {
        "CycleTime": .75,
        "Demand": 820,
      }

    ]
}]
```

if i do `console.log("The Data of weekly is", this.myData[0].weekly[0]);`

I'm able to get the data object but not able to iterate

```
for(let i=0; i > this.myData[0].weekly.length; i++) {
   this.WeeklyData = [this.myData[0].weekly[i]].push(this.WeeklyData);
 }
```

WeeklyData is not having data it is showing as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
this.WeeklyData = [...this.myData[0].weekly[i], ...this.WeeklyData];
```

Comment: this.WeeklyData is declared as any type and assigned empty array. this.WeeklyData = [];

Comment: ahh, hint's in @Felix answer, `i >` should be `i <`, and you can apply my ans

Answer (score 0):

You have it reversed... it should be

```
this.WeeklyData = [];
for(let i=0; i <= this.myData[0].weekly.length; i++) {
   this.WeeklyData.push(this.myData[0].weekly[i]);
}
```

And, of course you have `i >` where it should be `i <=`

You can also push the whole array, as in

```
this.WeeklyData.push(this.myData[0].weekly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I hope it's helpful.

it's ES6 standard.

Thanks

```
for(let i=0; i < this.myData[0].weekly.length; i++) {
  this.WeeklyData = [...this.WeeklyData,this.myData[0].weekly[i]]
 }
```